# Link and button not aligning

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

so I am relatively new to JavaScript, HTML and CSS but I am trying to create a button that links to another page, which is working, but the problem is that the link sticks out the side of the button, so even if I click outside the button, it will still take me to the link.

The only styling I did to the buttons were:

```css
.nav-buttons {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<Nav className="mr-auto">
  <Navbar.Toggle />
  <Link to="/about" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
    <Button className="nav-buttons">About</Button>
  </Link>
  <Link to="/projects" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
    <Button className="nav-buttons">Projects</Button>
  </Link> 
</Nav>
```

Here is an image:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `button`, you only need the link. The purpose of the `a` element is to link to another valid web address, which this is.

You should not try to nest links and buttons within each other since they have different purposes.

Comment: So, I got rid of the buttons, and added all the button styling to the <Link> tag however, it now doesn't look like a button at all. Is there any way I can keep the aesthetics of the button?

Comment: You can style the links to look like buttons. From the snippet above I can see that there were a number of classess added to the `button`, you can add them to the links instead.